# Finding the length of intersected line given a square of 3 equal rectangles and a perpendicular line

Tags: geometry

This is probably very straight forward, but I'm drawing a blank..

I want to find the length of $A-I$. This isn't a trick question, if anything looks slightly off, it's just a bad drawing. It's essentially a square divided into three $1/3$ rectangles.

Using the givens, I know $D-C = 316.227766$ and therefore, $D-H = 158.113883$, but I'm just drawing a blank on moving forward since it's been a while since I've done basic geometry..

[image: question diagram]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using 'pure' geometry, notice that $H$ is the midpoint of square $ABEF$. Then point $I$ is a $90º$ rotation clockwise from point $D$. Furthermore, $DH = IH$ because $AB = BE = EF = FA$.

Since $DHI$ is a right angle, $DI^2 = DH^2 + DH^2$ by Pythagoras' theorem. $DH^2 = 50^2 + 150^2$, so $DI^2 = 50000$. Triangle $ADI$ is again a right triangle, so $AI^2 + AD^2 = DI^2$. Therefore $AI = \sqrt{DI^2-DA^2} = \sqrt{50000 -200^2} = 100$.

Answer (score 0):

Using coordinate geometry, let $A$ be the origin. Then point $D$ is at $(0, -200)$, and point $C$ is at $(300, -100)$. Therefore, the midpoint $H$ is $\left(\frac{0+300}{2}, \frac{-200+(-100)}{2} \right) = (150, -150)$.

The slope of the line $DC$ is $\frac{\text{rise}}{\text{run}} = \frac{100}{300} = \frac{1}{3}$. Therefore, the slope of the perpendicular which is $IH$ is $\frac{-1}{1/3} = -3$. You know that the equation of $IH$ is $y = mx + c \Rightarrow = y = -3x + c$.

Substitute the coordinates of point $H$ in the equation to find $c$, and then substitute $y = 0$ to find the $x$-coordinate of point $I$ (since point $I$ lies on the $x$-axis). The $x$-coordinate of point $I$ will be the distance from $A$, as $A$ is the origin.

There is definitely a better way using pure geometry, which is probably what you expected, but I'll leave it for other people to answer.